# Mongodb querying for all min values that match criteria and indexing

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I had the following:

```
[
  {
    "team": "A",
    "age": 1,
    "name": "Abe"
  },
  {
    "team": "A",
    "age": 5,
    "name": "Apple"
  },
  {
    "team": "B",
    "age": 1,
    "name": "Ben"
  },
  {
    "team": "B",
    "age": 2,
    "name": "Bon"
  },
  {
    "team": "C",
    "age": 5,
    "name": "Cherry"
  }
]
```

I have the following query:
They must be in either TeamA or TeamB.
After filtering, I want only the youngest.

So in this example, it would return only Abe and Ben.

Preferably, I want it done in a single query. My guess is I have to use an aggregation pipeline, something like

```
db.People.aggregate(
[
    $match: { $or: [{ team: 'A' }, { team: 'B' }] },
    
    // some more stuff
);
```

Question1: I'm not sure what the next step would be. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Question2:
There may be a million records and I was thinking of adding two index:

1. Index on Team. I'm thinking this will allow it to filter Teams of interest.
2. Index on Age so that it can grab only the mins.

Would these indexes help or what kind of indexes should I be looking into?

**Edit: I'm getting closer, but I'm only interested in the records themselves. **

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          team: "A"
        },
        {
          team: "B"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$age",
      items: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1,
    
  }
])
```

Comment: You can group on team and get the minimum age.

Comment: I do not want the min age in each group. But I think I got it working. I edited my post. However, I'm not sure if this is the best approach and I'm still not sure about the indexes.

Comment: Nevermind. I'm getting closer, but it's not in exact format I want yet.